# what is SQLPlus command to view a VIEW statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I just found out that one of the queries I am running is not coming from actual table, it is coming from a VIEW.

I would like to see the SQL query in that VIEW. If I try to `describe` I get an object does not exist error. When I SELECT from the view I get some data.

Comment: Views should behave exactly the same way as tables do and AFAIK anyone with select privileges should be able to do a describe. Are you sure you're querying for the same view/table?

Answer (score 9):

To see the SQL underlying a view, you'll need to query the data dictionary. Try

```
select view_name, text from user_views where view_name = 'MY_VIEW';
```

If your user does not own the view, then try `all_views`;

Comment: thanks for great select command, but I am not able to find even when I do select * from all_views and where VIEW_NAME = `name_of_my_view'` I know for fact it is a VIEW, because I am using other software to write query and it shows it under view tab, not under table or function, but I cannot edit the view or view the code of the view.

Comment: Make sure you specify your view name as an UPPER case string. Also, are you sure this is a view? It maybe a materialized view. If so, then query `user_mviews` or `all_mviews`.

Comment: this shows only partial part of the select. how do i see the full view definition?

Comment: There is a `text_vc` (varchar) field too, that stores the whole query.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to see the actual SQL used to create the view you can use the function [`dbms_metadata.get_ddl`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_metada.htm#i1019414), which returns a clob:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl ( 'VIEW'
                             , 'MY_VIEW' -- view name
                                )
  from dual
```

There are a few more options if you need them.

If you want to just [describe](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve019.htm#SQPUG040) it as usual. If this is not working you're in the wrong schema or the object does not exist:

```
DESC MY_VIEW
```

If you're in the incorrect schema you can use:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl ( 'VIEW'
                             , 'MY_VIEW', -- view name
                             , 'MY_SCHEMA'
                                )
  from dual
```

or

```
DESC MY_SCHEMA.MY_VIEW
```

Comment: I get following error for 3rd option `desc my_schema.my_view --(view name)` `ORA-04043: object my_schema.actforevent does not exist`

Comment: @Mogli, it might not... are you sure that the view exists in that schema?

Comment: yes, I can see the view for that user database, but I cannot edit or view tht VIEW from the software I use to write sql query.

Comment: What does `select object_type from all_objects where object_name = 'MY_VIEW'` return?

Comment: It returns `no rows selected`

Comment: In that case you _cannot_ see whatever object this is from the schema you are in. If you have DBA privileges change it to `select ... from dba_objects ...`, and then connect to the correct schema and grant select to the one you are working in.

Comment: how and where can I change those privillages, I have Sql developer. thats all and I am not DBA.

Answer (score 0):

Or better yet, Click on the view in the left connections pane in SQLDeveloper. Once the view opens click on the SQL Tab to see the underlying SQL on it. To find which user/schema the view is in use

```
select owner 
   from all_objects 
   where object_name='VIEW_NAME' and object_type='VIEW';
```

Comment: It returns no rows selected. I replaced VIEW with name of my view.

Comment: replace `VIEW_NAME` with the name of your view. `Object_type='VIEW'` should not be changed.

Comment: How can I tell it to select view from particular DB user/owner

Comment: `select * from schema.view_name;` , schema is the DB User or owner.